# Not sure how to change a line - Crontab script for Spamassassin update fails with the error: unexpected operator

Tags: cron, services

A real newbie question. Not an experienced user at all, so please walk me through this

I have a cron daemon error and have been told to

> +++ Symptoms
>
> ```
> Parallels Plesk Panel sends mail with the following error:
>
> "Cron <root@$hostname> test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report
> /etc/cron.daily ) (failed)"
>
> "/etc/cron.daily/60sa-update:
> [: 9: 1: unexpected operator
> [: 14: 1: unexpected operator
> run-parts: /etc/cron.daily/60sa-update exited with return code 1"
> ```
>
> Cause On Debian, /bin/sh is a symlink to "dash."
>
> ```
> # ls -la /bin/sh
> lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 2010-06-14 06:06 /bin/sh -> dash
> ```
>
> The script can fail to execute if it contains #!/bin/sh as hashbang.
>   Resolution To fix this error, update the file
>   /etc/cron.daily/60sa-update. Replace `#!/bin/sh` with `#!/bin/bash`.
>
> The script for the Spamassassin update should then be able to execute
>   without error.
>
> ++++

I can get access onto my SSH, but just don't have a clue of the various command prompts I then need to enter, in order to change the line required.

Could someone kindly take me through step by step.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use a text editor with root permissions

```
sudoedit /etc/cron.daily/60sa-update
```

or

```
sudo nano /etc/cron.daily/60sa-update
```

Make the change described, and then save the file and exit: for `nano`, that would be <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>